# Saving data of dependent drop-down - Yii

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, yii

I am implementing a dependent drop-down and want to save their IDs in the table CANDIDATE.
I have a table named as CENTER which has two columns ID, NAME.
My other table is DISTRICT which has three columns ID, NAME and CENTER_ID.
 
By selecting the CENTER , I am populating the DISTRICT drop-down but the district_id is not being saved in the table CANDIDATE .
**_form**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'district_id'); ?>
    <?php

    $dist = CHtml::listData(Center::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'id')), 'id', 'name');
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'center_id', $dist, array(
        'prompt' => '–select district–',
        'ajax' => array('type' => 'POST',
            'url' => CController::createUrl('candidate/districts'),
            'update' => '#center_id',

        )

    ));
    ?>
    <?php
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('center_id','', array());
    ?>
</div>
```

**CandidateController**

```
 public function actionDistricts() {
    $centers = District::model()->findAll('center_id =:id', array(':id' => (int) $_POST['Candidate']['center_id']));
    $return = CHtml::listData($centers, 'id', 'name');
    foreach ($return as $centerId  => $centerName) {
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $centerId), CHtml::encode($centerName), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) It seems like your url is not properly created:

```
'url' => CController::createUrl('districts')
```

Try:

```
'url' => CController::createUrl('candidate/districts')
```

2) The form you post:

```
$form->dropDownList($model, 'district_id', $dist...
```

It posts district_id to CandidateController/actionDistricts(), where you do following:

```
 $centers = Center::model()->findAll('id=:id', array(':id' => (int) $_POST['Candidate']['center_id']));
```

I can't see any input containing center_id, moreover, firing Center::model()->findAll('id:id'..) doesn't make sense, if you search by primary key (id), do Center::model()->findByPk($id);

Anyways, back to the problem, your firebug log sais it all, it can't read center_id form $_POST variable, so to finish it up, try rewriting actionDistricts().

I can't guess what kind of relation (one district, several centers per 1?) your db has, so i wont be able to fully fix the problem here. But you should rewrite

$centers = Center::model()->findAll('id=:id', array(':id' => (int) $_POST['Candidate']['center_id']));

to something that expects $_POST['Candidate']['district_id'].

Comment: After looking at your firebug trace, I guess problem is that you send district_id to your actionDistricts, but on the server end you try to read $_POST['Candidate']['center_id']

Comment: i have been able to populate dropdown but i am still unable to save the id of district in CANDIDATE table. As for relations CENTER has one to many relation with DISTRICT.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
'url' => CController::createUrl('districts'),
```

By

```
 'url' => $this::createUrl('candidate/districts'),
```